# pyqt not responding during reading a file

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, no-response

my GUI with PyQt is showing not responding during I´m reading in a method a file and calculating an Output, which will shown in the table of the QWidget.

Thus it takes some seconds for reading the lines in the file and I should find a better solution for the user than the "not responding". Is there a way to get around it or Maybe a waiting Symbol to inform the user it´s just working.

Thanks guys!

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single-Thread application, it would be *impossible* to do two things together: reading a file and handling the GUI.

Try to use multi-threading. Have a look of this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html 
or this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html

Also have a look of this page specified for https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

And an explanation on StackOverflow of multi-threading of GUI application:
[Explanation of need for Multi Threading GUI programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343096/explanation-of-need-for-multi-threading-gui-programming)

**A small example for multi-threading in python:**

```py
def readingAFile(path):
    doSomething()
    showTheDataToGUI()

def main():
    _thread.start_new_thread(readingAFile, (filePath, ))
```